# No default proposals in Eclipse when working with XML

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, default

So i  started learning javaFX.
And ive succesfully added javadocumentation in Eclipse when working with XML, but normally when im working with Java in Eclipse i get default recommendations with methods or when typing in java i get recommendations. These are really nice and i often scroll trough them just to see what methods there are and play around if i see anything interesting.
When working in XML files i do not get the recommendations at all, ive tried alot of stuff and dont wanna break something since i just started on JavaFX and finally configured most things correctly :P

Can anyone please help me ?

Thanks in  advance!!

Info: JDK 11

JavaFX version 11

[This is someone who does get the default proposal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHoJA.png)

[I do not get any kind of proposal when typing at all just to show here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLXTT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to open xml file with proper editor in Eclipse.
Select xml file => click with right mouse button => Open with => XML Editor

Then you can press "Strg + Space" while typing and you should get the proposals.

You can also check your Content Assist settings here:
Eclipse Menu => Window => Preferences 
XML => XML Files => Editor => Content Assist
Here you can check things like "Automatically make suggestions"

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion ive changed the settings, it helped! ive also changed the "Activate when typing" setting into every letter of my keyboard to keep giving me default proposals while typing :)

Thankyou again!

Answer (score 0):

Please add the Rest Assured latest JAR Externally. It is working. I was also facing the same issue but now it is working for me. [Check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMgn6.png)